# Is $a^m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a^n \in \mathbb{R}$ sufficient for $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose $a, m, n \in \mathbb{R}$. In real-number arithmetic, is $a^m \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $a^n \in \mathbb{R}$ sufficient for $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$?

---

**Edit:** Symbolically, is it true that $$\forall a, m, n \in \mathbb{R} : [a^m, a^n \in \mathbb{R} \implies (a^m)^n=a^{mn}]$$ for the usual exponentiation on $\mathbb{R}$ (a partial binary function that is undefined for some combinations of base and exponent values, e.g. for $0^0$ and $(-1)^{1/2}$)?

If true, this would allow for negative bases in applications of this rule.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$ ?

Comment: Remember $1=(e^{2\pi i})^{\frac 12} \ne e^{\pi i}=-1$ but $e^{2\pi i}=1\in \mathbb R$ and $e^{\frac 12} \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch a, m and are all real numbers.

Comment: @fleablood I am just considering arithmetic on the real numbers.

Comment: "Sufficient" is a very strange way of putting it then.  Among real numbers if $a^m, a^n$ is defined then $(a^m)^n= a^{mn}$ is a basic property.  ... Okay, I guess there are issues if $a \le 0$ but.... okay.... if $a^m$ is defined (which it isn't if $a< 0$ and $m$ is fraction with an even denominator) then this holds.  .... okay, it's just me but "sufficient" threw me for a loop.

Comment: @fleablood It's not just you, because I don't understand the question either ... what if it's just you and me? ... but seriously, using the expressions $a^m$ and $a^n$ presupposes that they have been defined, yet they have no standard definition that applies to all real values, nor has reference been made to any non-standard definition that might apply in some cases. The expression $a^m \in \mathbb{R}$ logically cannot substitute for a *definition* of the constituent expression $a^m.$ (I still can't escape the feeling that the confusion is all mine! But I have tried to show the reason for it.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley the more I think about it, the more it works. But it just not the issue as *I* would have thought it.  If $a< 0$ then $a^{\frac 13}\ne \sqrt[3]{a} \ne \sqrt[6]{a^2}$ and $a^{\frac 12}$ is not defined but $a^2 = (a^4)^{\frac 12}$. And of course there's the famous $-1=e^{\pi i} = (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac 12}=\sqrt 1=1$ so... it makes sense to ask "how the heck do we hash out these rules?"... It's just that when I read "is it sufficient" I think it is more "when does $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$" rather than "what does it mean" type question. But can't expect OPs to critique their own questions.

Comment: What root are you taking when n or m is not integer?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse I am just assuming that $a, m,n, a^m, a^n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you want to know whether  forall a,m,n e R (a^m e R /\ a^n e R => (a^m)^n = a^(m n)) is true, a theorem? It depends on the (^)/2 operator.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse Yes. Not interested here in complex numbers, just real numbers.

Comment: But you are interested where the (^)/2 operator is undefined?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse It is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: But for the question to be relevant you need to have situations where a^n e R doesn't hold. How do you model a^n e R if (^)/2 is a partial function?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse Yes, a partial binary function that is undefined for some combinations of base and exponent values, e.g. for $0^0$ and $(-1)^{1/2}$. So we might have $\forall x,y: [(x,y)\in D \implies x^y \in \mathbb{R}]$ where  $D\subset \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If $a>0$, then the identity holds universally. If $a<0$, then you are implying that $m$ and $n$ are rational numbers with odd denominator, in which case $a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$. A quick way to see this is by using the fact that, for $q$ odd, $b\ne 0$ and $h$ integer, $(-\lvert b\rvert)^{h/q}=(-1)^h\lvert b\rvert^{h/q}$. Therefore $$((-\lvert a\rvert)^{h_1/q_1})^{h_2/q_2}=((-1)^{h_1}\lvert a\rvert^{h_1/q_1})^{h_2/q_2}=(-1)^{h_1h_2}\lvert a\rvert^{h_1h_2/(q_1q_2)}\\ (-\lvert a\rvert)^{h_1h_2/(q_1q_2)}=(-1)^{h_1h_2}\lvert a\rvert^{h_1h_2/(q_1q_2)}$$ If $a=0$, depending on the convention, you are implying that $m$ and $n$ are strictly positive real numbers (or, if $0^0=1$, non-negative real numbers). Either way, $0^{mn}=(0^m)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^b, (a^b)^c, (a^{bc})$ are defined and we are only using real numbers then $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

It is completely fundamental that $a^{b+k} = a^ba^k$ and so if $bc = \underbrace{b+b+....+b}_{c\text{ times}}$ then $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.  ("But what if $c$ isn't an integ..." *whack*.... don't pay any attention to that voice under the carpet.)

If any of them are undefined for any reason, say $a<0$ and $b$ is a fraction with an even denominator in its lowest term, or if $a=b=0$ then it's not so much that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ is false (it isn't) but that the statement is meaningless as it has undefined terms.

======

With complex number we can define all $a^b$ (except for $a=b=0$).  But that thing is it is multivalued.  What is $a^{\frac 12}$?  Well, it is the number $k$ so that $k^2 = a$.  But... if $k^2 = a$ then $(-k)^2 = a$ also... which one is $a^{\frac 12}$.  Well, the answer is... the both are.  Or more  $a^{\frac 12}$ is a set of two values so that $k^2 = a$.

So can we say $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.  Well, the issue isn't that it *isn't* true.  It's that there are multiple values of $a^b$ and of $(a^b)^c$ and $a^{bc}$ and for at least one set they *will* synch up but others can be notational trickery and not make sense.

There's an old paradox.  $i = \sqrt{-1}$.  (which isn't really true; $i^2 = -1$ but $\sqrt{-1} = $ the *set* of both $i$ and $-i$.)

Then $1 = \sqrt{1*1} = \sqrt{-1*-1} = \sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{-1} = i*i=i^2 = -1$.

If you ask must people where the error is they'll say the rule $(ab)^{k} = a^kb^k$ only holds for positive numbers.  Which is *partially* true.

But more to the point there are multiple values that $\sqrt{}$ can be.

$1$ can be one thing: 1.  And $\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{1*1} =\sqrt{-1*-1}$ can be two things: $1, -1$.  And $\sqrt{-1}$ can be two things: $i$ and $-i$.  And $\sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{-1}$ can be four things:  $i*i = -1; i*(-i) = 1; (-i)*i=1; (-i)*(-i) = -1$.  and as inclusions... it's true:  $1 \in \{1,-1\}$ but we can't reverse the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The "rule" $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ doesn't necessarily hold when $a < 0$.

Comment: But $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not a real number, whereas the OP demands that $a^m$ and $a^n$ are real numbers.